# I can't install react using npx create-react-app is this aNodist the issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've received the following in the debug log. I'm looking to npx create-react-app. The terminal is returning

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-07T14_57_21_064Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1

This is the debug file...

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\v-x64\\18.1.0\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\bin\\node_modules\\npx\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'create-react-app@latest',
1 verbose cli   '--global',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\50292',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   '--json'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@5.1.0
3 info using node@v18.1.0
4 verbose npm-session 56a59e1a77678c6d
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 102ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote tag manifest for create-react-app@latest fetched in 165ms
9 verbose stack TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
9 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\npx\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:287:18
9 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:204:5)
10 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\Websites\react
11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\v-x64\\18.1.0\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\bin\\node_modules\\npx\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-react-app@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\50292" "--loglevel" "error" "--json"
13 verbose node v18.1.0
14 verbose npm  v5.1.0
15 error cb.apply is not a function
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm using the latest beta version of Node, so I'll try to go back to the latest stable version. If that doesn't work, I'll try to re-download node away from nodist..

If you have any other thoughts or suggestions Perhaps there is a hint in the debug log, then I'd be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion under github https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/discussions/10173#discussioncomment-142156

you need to

```
npm rm -g create-react-app
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to remove and npx without the install step?

Comment: npx should install that for you automatically

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the Nodist version manager. I installed nvm and I'm now able to get npx to work without a problem. I think the issue for me was that I was using the nodist version manager.

Highly recommend checking out nvm here if you get similar issues.
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/wiki